# PostgreSQL DATE_PART function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find all applications whose time of sending all documents does not exceed 10 minutes. I have done the rest of code but I have problem with date_part function. The code below works fine but I have to find the other way. How can I do it differently ?

```
abs(
    round(
        (
            date_part('hour',d.received_date)
            - 
            date_part('hour',d.send_date)
        ) * 60
        + 
        (
            date_part('minute', d.received_date)
            -
            date_part('minute', d.send_date)
        )
    )
) as sendTime
```

Comment: Why do you need to find another way?  If you could add the relevant create table statements so we could see the table structure, it would be much easier to answer this question.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  This site is an English-language site, so your query and question have no relationship to each other.

Comment: I'm very sorry I forgot to change the values.

Comment: abs(round((date_part('hour',d.recived_date)- 
date_part('hour',d.post_date))*60+ (date_part('minute', 
d.recived_date)-date_part('minute', d.post_date)))) as 
czaswysylki

Comment: `where r.received_date - r.send_date  <= interval '10' minute`?

Comment: case when d.recived_date - d.send_date <= interval '10' minute THEN 'True' END 
    as "send time"        Yes but it gives me a result like 'true' or 'Null'. I need in "send time"  results in minutes like 2 or 7 or 9 e.t.c

Comment: then just select `r.received_date - r.send_date` and check this site for expressions that convert an `interval` to the number of minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me if you want to limit the result to rows where the difference is less then 10 minutes (as stated in the question) or you just want to display the result between two timestamps in minutes (as you stated in the comments).

The expression `r.received_date - r.send_date` returns an [`interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) which can easily to be converted to minutes. So to display the difference, use:

```
extract(epoch from d.received_date - d.send_date) / 60 as minutes
```

to limit the result to only rows where the difference is less than 10 minutes use:

```
select ...
from ...
where d.received_date - d.send_date <= interval '10' minute
```